# api3 and contact.is_deleted when using "return", and discrepancy between api explorer and php code?

Tags: api

**Scenario**:

Contact id 2, is_deleted is set to 1. Permissions not an issue since running as admin and no acl's present.

**Results**:

- api3 explorer: Ask for return value "contact is in trash" which translates to `'return' => ['is_deleted']`, so in full `civicrm_api3('contact', 'get', ['id' => 2, 'return' => ['is_deleted']]);`. This returns 0 results in api3 explorer (which is wrong).
- command line with cv: also no results
- command line with cv but change is_deleted to contact_is_deleted: `civicrm_api3('contact', 'get', ['id' => 2, 'return' => ['contact_is_deleted']]);`. This does return results.
- Seeing same on 5.35 and master. I don't remember having this issue before but maybe I never put it in the `return` clause. It does work as a "where" clause on the command line, e.g. `civicrm_api3('contact', 'get', ['id' => 2, 'is_deleted' => 1]);`, but not in api3 explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Certain field values are blocked through ajax call that includes from api explorer as well. The ajax call makes check permission to true by default and cannot be over-riden from api params. The result may vary incase calling from php or smarty

Comment: When you say "blocked" do you mean that if I specify is_deleted as a return value and am using ajax api, then it's on purpose that it doesn't return any records? It's not a permissions issue - everything in this case is running as admin.